# Как повернуть текст в Kofax Transformation?

Tags: текст, rotation

С Кофакс только начинаю работать.

Вот ссылка на тот же вопрос на английском:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501565/how-to-rotate-text-in-kofax-transformation

Интересует поворот на 90/180/270 градусов именно отдельного фрагмента страницы (текста), а не всей страницы целиком. С распознаванием, естественно. Подавляющее большинство текста в другом направлении. Почему это легко можно сделать в Kofax Capture, но нельзя (?) в Kofax Transformation? В чём логика???

Text Rotation in Kofax Capture: Recognition Profiles -> Kofax High Rerfomance OCR Zonal -> Advanced -> Engine and other -> Text orientation

Если всё же нельзя (хотелось бы по крайней мере получить внятный ответ да/нет, чтобы больше не терять времени на поиски, домыслы...), то существуют ли какие-нибудь пути обхода этой проблемы в Kofax Transformation?

Перерыл много документации и в коробке, и в интернете. Не нашёл хоть сколько-нибудь подходящего решения (через резиновую рамку там и пр.). Видимо, всё упирается в невозможность OCR'ить в модуле валидации. Быть может, я чего-то в упор не вижу? Неужели нельзя???

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Был получен исчерпывающий ответ на англоязычном варианте вопроса:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501565/how-to-rotate-text-in-kofax-transformation

Изложение основных моментов из ответа:

KTM оперирует Page Profiles и Zone Profiles онли. Никаких "Word Profiles" и т.п. не существует.

Я пропустил-таки опцию из коробки для Zone Profile: Advanced Zone Locator -> Zones -> Properties -> General -> Rotation.

Сори, уж больно закопали :) Однако это поможет лишь в случае, если зона имеет статичное расположение на странице. Если зона может "гулять" туда-сюда, предлагается 2 дополнительных подхода:

1) двигать AZL скриптом, используя в качестве якоре какой-нибудь другой локатор, напр., Format Loactor. Нек. приёмы для этого здесь: http://knowledgebase.kofax.com/faqsearch/results.aspx?QAID=17759

2) Если нельзя двинуть AZL (напр., из-за слабых якорей), идти через Page Profile. Принципиально: моё предположение из постановки вопроса "Видимо, всё упирается в невозможность OCR'ить в модуле валидации." оказалось неверным, к счастью. Распознавать в скрипте можно! И, что важно, можно дважды, трижды и т.д. Это открывает широчайший диапазон возможностей! Для этого нужно с редакторе скриптов подключить доп. функционал (dll), содержащий движок распознавания, напр., Kofax Memphis FineReader. Автор англоязычного ответа предлагает сначала положить страницу набок целиком, затем заново распознать с использованием подключённого движка. При этом будут адекватно распознаны только слова, кот. "раньше" были вертикальными. Остальные слова при этом будут мусором, ес-сно. Затем смёрджить оба варианта в объектах Representations. Пример повторного распознавания из скрипта здесь: https://www.theorycrafter.org/quipu/swapping-ocr-representations-in-ktm/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/429695)

Comment: Дополнил ссылку из ответа автономным содержанием.